# Can we order bulk coupon codes from apple app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

We have an iOS app that is in the first aid industry. We want to be able to offer it in 2 ways.

1.) Purchasing the app via IAP

2.) Having a distributor purchase 100 coupon codes that their students can use to download and use the app without having to do an IAP for the rest of the content.

The problem is with the coupon codes. Apple will obviously not allow us to generate coupon codes outside the app store system because they won't get their commission.

We want to know if there is a way to purchase bulk orders of coupon codes from apple that we can then give to our distributors of our program and they can in turn give to their students.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: No, you cannot do that; It's against Apple's rules.

Comment: Thanks Will. So there is no way at all to pay apple in bulk for coupon codes to achieve this?

Comment: Looks like  Volume Purchase Program from Apple might be the answer.. I have to look into this more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look into the Volume Purchasing Program. Your distributor would need to sign up for that through Apple and that would allow you so sell multiple copies of the App to the distributor who could then distribute individual claim codes for the app.

See: [Apple VPP](https://vpp.itunes.apple.com/us/store)